# How to keep mouseover triggered and only stop the action when the cursor leaves the element?

Tags: javascript, html

This code adds a mouseover eventListener to the parent of the element:

```
const el = this.$refs.tooltip
el.parentElement.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  el.style.display = 'block'
  setTimeout(() => {
    el.style.display = 'none'
  }, 500)
})
```

However, the tooltip disappears even when the cursor stays on the parent.

How to keep the tooltip displaying and only make it disappear when the cursor leaves the element's parent?

Comment: use [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) to detect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var parent = el.parentElement;
parent.addEventListener("mouseover",() => {el.style.display = 'block'});
parent.addEventListener("mouseout",() => {el.style.display = 'none'});
```

// take care of parent dom structure because mouseout will fire from any children

// take care of ()=>{... this ...} syntax  because will not bind 'this' to parent while function(ev){... this ...} does